# How value is passed into user defined compare function in treeset

Tags: java, treeset

Here is a code of treeset of user defined object.

```
package com.java2novice.treeset;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MyCompUserDefine {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        //By using name comparator (String comparison)
        TreeSet<Empl> nameComp = new TreeSet<Empl>(new MyNameComp());
        nameComp.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
        nameComp.add(new Empl("John",6000));
        nameComp.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
        nameComp.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
        for(Empl e:nameComp){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("===========================");
        //By using salary comparator (int comparison)
        TreeSet<Empl> salComp = new TreeSet<Empl>(new MySalaryComp());
        salComp.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
        salComp.add(new Empl("John",6000));
        salComp.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
        salComp.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
        for(Empl e:salComp){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class MyNameComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    }
}   

class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if(e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

class Empl{

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Empl(String n, int s){
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
    }
}
```

My question is when I am calling MyNameComp() or MySalaryComp() then I am just calling its constructor without passing any value. But how value or object of EMP1 class are passed by?

Answer (score 1):

The `TreeSet` objects that you create are responsible for using the comparator you passed when instantiating it.

How the `TreeSet` does it should not concern you because it's an implementation detail. The `TreeSet` just guarantees that the comparator you provide will be used when necessary. You don't need to think about it... but just for the heck of it, let's look at the source (please mind that you should not rely on implementation details of any classes as they are free to change, when consuming an API, you can only be sure of what's an explicit part of the interface!)

Let's start with the [`TreeSet` constructor that takes a `Comparator` as an argument](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java#TreeSet.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Comparator%29), this is what you're calling when you create your `TreeSet` instances in the examples provided

```
public More ...TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    this(new TreeMap<E,Object>(comparator));
}
```

We can see that [the constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java#TreeSet.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Comparator%29) uses the comparator to instantiate a `TreeMap` calls another `TreeSet` constructor. The `TreeMap` created here will be used to store the items in the `TreeSet`.

Let's leave it at that without inspecting what happens inside the `TreeMap`. We just need to know that the `TreeMap` is what actually stores the items. This knowledge will come in handy when we take a look at what happens when you add elements.

You're inserting all items using the [`TreeSet#add` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java#TreeSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29), which uses the same map that got created when you called the constructor.

```
public boolean More ...add(E e) {
    return m.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

The `m` object is the `TreeMap` instantiated inside the constructor. Since we know it's a `TreeMap` and that the `put` method is used, we can have a look at what it does.

Here's the implementation of [`TreeMap#put`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

This method uses a comparator that, upon closer inspection, turns out to be the same one that was used when creating the `TreeMap` in the `TreeSet` constructor.

```
 public V More ...put(K key, V value) {
     Entry<K,V> t = root;
     if (t == null) {
         // TBD:
         // 7: (coll) Adding null to an empty TreeSet should
         // throw NullPointerException
         //
         // compare(key, key); // type check
         root = new Entry<K,V>(key, value, null);
         size = 1;
         modCount++;
         return null;
     }
     int cmp;
     Entry<K,V> parent;
     // split comparator and comparable paths
     Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
     if (cpr != null) {
         do {
             parent = t;
             cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
             if (cmp < 0)
                 t = t.left;
             else if (cmp > 0)
                 t = t.right;
             else
                 return t.setValue(value);
         } while (t != null);
     }
     else {
         if (key == null)
             throw new NullPointerException();
         Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
         do {
             parent = t;
             cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
             if (cmp < 0)
                 t = t.left;
             else if (cmp > 0)
                 t = t.right;
             else
                 return t.setValue(value);
         } while (t != null);
     }
     Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<K,V>(key, value, parent);
     if (cmp < 0)
         parent.left = e;
     else
         parent.right = e;
     fixAfterInsertion(e);
     size++;
     modCount++;
     return null;
 }
```

This is a little complicated and you'd have to read through the rest of the implementation to gain a complete understanding of what's happening here but it's clearly visible that the provided comparator gets used.

The bottom line here, however, is that this **should not matter to you or your code as the client of the collections API**. You should only rely on what's explicitly stated in the Javadoc of the `public` or `protected` methods.

You can take a look at [the JDK 8 version](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) to see that the internals have changed (although very slightly)

The reason you can be sure that a `TreeMap` and the provided `Comparator` will be used is because it's part of `TreeSet`'s API. To quote the [`TreeSet` Javadoc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeSet.java#TreeSet):

> (a `TreeSet` is) A `NavigableSet` implementation based on a `TreeMap`. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a `Comparator` provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Changing any of these things would break the contract.

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet keeps its elements sorted. If you provide a comparator, it uses that custom comparator (in your case  MyNameComp() or MySalaryComp()) to compare and sort them. You dont need to call anything, TreeSet will handle it internally.